# Create paragraph bullets in slides using java

Tags: java, google-slides-api

I'm trying to generate slide with **nested bullets** using Google Slides API with **Java**. 
I've followed the documentation in implementing it, However I'm getting nested bullets but not intended (nested with different bullet style coming left aligned).

Please go through the images & code for better understanding of my issue.

**Expected:**

[image]

**Getting:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
Requests.add(new Request().setInsertText(new InsertTextRequest().setObjectId(shapeId).setText("Bold\nItal 2\n\tFoo\n\tBar\n\tBla")) ); 

Requests.add(new Request().setCreateParagraphBullets(new CreateParagraphBulletsRequest().setObjectId(shapeId).setTextRange(new Range().setType("ALL")) ));
```

Any suggestions on where I'm going wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Based from Google Slide API documentation about [Bullet glyph Text style](https://developers.google.com/slides/concepts/text#bullet_glyph_text_style):

> Like normal text, **bullet glyphs** have a text style that controls how
>   the glyph is rendered. These text styles ***cannot be modified*** using the
>   Slides API directly. However, if you use an [`UpdateTextStyleRequest`](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#updatetextstylerequest) to
>   update a complete paragraph that includes a bullet, the Slides API
>   updates the bullet glyph's text style to match.
>
> Bullet glyph text styles follow a slightly different inheritance
>   hierarchy than normal text styles.
>
> 1. A bullet at a certain nesting level first inherits from the `TextStyle` set in the `NestingLevel.bullet_style` field inside the
>      bullet's `List` object.
> 2. It next inherits from the corresponding `NestingLevel.bullet_style` in its parent placeholder's `List`.
> 3. Finally it seeks to inherit from remaining parent placeholder objects.